# What's the number of cards per rarity in a regular set of MTG?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I am trying to do a calculation for modern masters that is coming out next year and to complete it I need to know, How many commons, uncommons, rares and mythics are in a regular set of mtg(Scars of mirrodin for example)?

Comment: The size of regular sets can vary drastically. You can get the numbers for each set [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Magic:_The_Gathering_sets).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Modern Masters contains 229 cards (101 commons, 60 uncommons, 53 rares, and 15 mythic rares).

The Scars of Mirrodin set contains 249 cards (101 common, 60 uncommon, 53 rare, 15 mythic rare, and 20 basic land).

http://www.wizards.com/Magic/Magazine/Article.aspx?x=mtg/daily/feature/218

Answer (score 1):

Sets have varied in size. From Antiquities being only 100 cards to 5th edition at 449 cards. There really is no standard. There are however some things generally true about set size. The first set in a block is larger than the other two, meant to set the card base for the others to add to. Core sets are usually on par with or larger then the first set in a block.

For general information -

- The average size of a core set is: 311 cards
- The average size of the first set of a block is: 303 cards
- The average size of the second or third set in a block is : 170 cards

As pointed out by Malco, this is changing with the release of Dominaria in April. WotC is doing away with blocks as a set structure. This will mean sets will likely all be something a little smaller than the 300 cards of a core or first set, but that's just my speculation based on the info MaRo has put out so far. Dominara will be 269 cards (+PW deck exclusives) which does fit that theory, but one set isn't proof.

Comment: ONe thing to note is that the way sets are laid out this has semi-recently changed. Check out [MaRo's article](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/making-magic/metamorphosis-2-0-2017-06-12) (about half way down) for how things will work in the future.